# Get cloc (count lines of code ) difference between 2 commits by date Git

Tags: gitlab, cloc

i tried the below command in git to get  cloc difference between two commits using commit ids and i got the result in beautiful table.

```
cloc --git --diff <commit id1> <commit id2>
```

But i need a CLOC difference between commits but instead of using commit ids i need to use dates as a parameter to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git rev-list` to get the commit SHAs you want for a particular date range.

For example, suppose you want to use the date range Jan 20, 2021 to Feb 20, 2021

```sh
branch=master
start_date=2021-01-20
end_date=2021-02-20

start_commit="$(git rev-list -n1 --before=${start_date} ${branch})"
end_commit="$(git rev-list -n1 --before=${end_date} ${branch})"

echo "Start commit for ${start_date} is ${start_commit}
echo "End commit for ${end_date} is ${end_commit}
```

Using this, you can plug `$start_commit` and `$end_commit` into your `cloc` command:

```sh
loc_count="$(cloc --git --diff ${start_commit} ${end_commit})"
echo "$loc_count"
```

Comment: sytech , how to run this commands in command prompt

Comment: cloc is not wokring in gitbash

Comment: @AnushaG the commands are the same in Windows, with the proper tools installed. The syntax would change a bit with the variables, but the principle remains exactly the same. -- `cloc` is not included in most Linux distributions or Windows by default, you'll need to [install it](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/#apt-get)

Comment: can you suggest any other commands

Comment: can you tell me how to run that commands in command prompt , i use set method to initialize the date and start_commit,end_commit but i am not getting the result